# Jump to a specific Preference Item in inAppSettingsKit plist

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, inappsettingskit

I have several IASKAppSettingsWebViewController items setup in my plist and I would like to jump to one specifically as soon as the IASKAppSettingsViewController is loaded.  How would I do this? THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instantiate a `IASKAppSettingsWebViewController` manually using

```
IASKSettingsReader *settingsReader = [[IASKSettingsReader alloc] initWithFile:@"Root.plist"];
IASKSpecifier *specifier = [settingsReader specifierForKey:@"key"];
IASKAppSettingsWebViewController *vc = [[IASKAppSettingsWebViewController alloc] initWithFile:@"Test.html" specifier:specifier];
```

Then just push this view controller on the IASK navigation controller.